# TF object detection: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm catching [this](https://pythonprogramming.net/video-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/?completed=/introduction-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/) tutorial about object detection API and I when I run the code, even if I don't use a webcam (that returns the same problem) I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\obj\models\research\object_detection\object_testmien_image.py", line 138, in <module>
    feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
  File "C:\Users\tomsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 905, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\tomsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1109, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
  File "C:\Users\tomsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 492, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

To open the video file I used a normal `cap = cv2.VideoCapture("F:\gopro\file.MOV)` is it correct?
Why does it return None?
Even though I have catch advices of other similar question it doesn't go.
Thank you for any advice!
The code is the same of the tutorial I linked.

Edit:
Here the code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("F:\gopro\file.MOV")

# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append("..")


# ## Object detection imports
# Here are the imports from the object detection module.

# In[3]:

from utils import label_map_util

from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util


# # Model preparation 

# ## Variables
# 
# Any model exported using the `export_inference_graph.py` tool can be loaded here simply by changing `PATH_TO_CKPT` to point to a new .pb file.  
# 
# By default we use an "SSD with Mobilenet" model here. See the [detection model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) for a list of other models that can be run out-of-the-box with varying speeds and accuracies.

# In[4]:

# What model to download.
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017'
MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')

NUM_CLASSES = 90


# ## Download Model

# In[5]:

opener = urllib.request.URLopener()                         #<-------- comment out by yt
opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)     #<-------- the same
tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
for file in tar_file.getmembers():
  file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)
  if 'frozen_inference_graph.pb' in file_name:
    tar_file.extract(file, os.getcwd())


# ## Load a (frozen) Tensorflow model into memory.

# In[6]:

detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')


# ## Loading label map
# Label maps map indices to category names, so that when our convolution network predicts `5`, we know that this corresponds to `airplane`.  Here we use internal utility functions, but anything that returns a dictionary mapping integers to appropriate string labels would be fine

# In[7]:

label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)


# ## Helper code

# In[8]:

def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
  print(image.size)
  (im_width, im_height) = image.size
  return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
      (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)


# # Detection

# In[9]:

# For the sake of simplicity we will use only 2 images:
# image1.jpg
# image2.jpg
# If you want to test the code with your images, just add path to the images to the TEST_IMAGE_PATHS.
PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'test_images'
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 'image{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 3) ]

# Size, in inches, of the output images.
IMAGE_SIZE = (12, 8)


# In[10]:

with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    while True:
      ret, image_np = cap.read()
      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
      # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
      boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
      # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
      # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
      scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
      classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
      num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
      # Actual detection.
      (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
          [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
      # Visualization of the results of a detection.
      vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(boxes),
          np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
          np.squeeze(scores),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=8)

      cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np, (800,600)))
      if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Comment: It seems that `image_np_expanded` evaluates to `None`, but it is impossible to say how or why without actually seeing any code.

Comment: I have just added the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python [backslashes are escape characters](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%E2%80%94-backslashes-are-escape-characters/). In order to use actual backslashes in the file path use:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("F:\\gopro\\file.MOV")
```

Or just use a [raw string](https://knowledge.kitchen/Raw_strings_in_Python):

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(r"F:\gopro\file.MOV")
```

As pointed out in the docs ([OpenCV 2](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read), [OpenCV 3](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html#videocapture-read)), `read()` return two values, a success indicator and the retrieved frame. You should always check the success indicator (`ret` in your code) before using the returned frame, which in this case is `None`.